# Last input added to a form in Laravel not inserting to database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I bought a ready made Laravel Tailor application, I am trying to add an additional input to it but after doing so, I tried to submit it to the database but the last one I added wasn't inserting. The input is in array.

All other values are inserting except for **service_description[]** which is newly added to the form.

What exactly could I be doing wrong?

Database Structure

[image]

**HTML Codes:**

```
@extends('admin.layouts.master')
@section('content')
<style type="text/css">

</style>
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role= "alert">
        <strong>Successful:</strong>
            {!! session('success') !!}
    </div>
@endif

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-06">
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
    <div class="portlet light bordered">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <i class="icon-equalizer font-red-sunglo"></i>
                <span class="caption-subject font-red-sunglo bold uppercase">Order Submission</span>
                <span class="caption-helper">Service Details</span>
            </div>
            <div class="tools">
                <a href="" class="collapse"> </a>
                <a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal" class="config"> </a>
                <a href="" class="reload"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body form">
            <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
            <form action="{{url('admin/save-order')}}" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                <input name="order_create_by" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"> 
                <div class="form-body">
                     {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <h3 class="form-section">Customer Info</h3>
                        <!--Start Customer Area-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <!-- text input -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="control-label col-md-4">Customer Name:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ..." name="service_cus_name" id="service_cus_name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="control-label col-md-4">Email Address:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ..." name="service_cus_email" id="service_cus_email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Order Create Date:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">  
                                                <div class="input-group date">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right createdpicker" name="service_crete_date" id="service_crete_date">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cell Number:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ..." name="cell_number" id="cell_number">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Order Delivery Date:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <div class="input-group date">
                                                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                  </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right dpicker" name="service_delivery_date" id="service_delivery_date">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                   <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Cutomer Address:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..." name="service_cus_address" id="service_cus_address"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!--End Customer Area-->
                        <!--Start Service Order Area-->             
                    <div class="form-section">
                        <h3 class="inlineBlock">Service Details with Measurement</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="btn dark flot-right " id="addService" disabled="disabled"> Add Another Service </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                             <label>Select Service</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                            <label>Rate:</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <label>Quantity:</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <label>Amount:</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <label>Action</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row serviceRow redBorder"  id="orderBox">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="col-md-11">
                                    <select class="form-control service_id" name="service_id[]" id="service_id">
                                        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="0">Select Service</option>
                                        @foreach($services as $service)
                                        <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->service_name}}</option>
                                      @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control service_price" placeholder="Rate" name="service_price[]" id="service_price" readonly>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control service_qty" placeholder="Quantity" id="service_qty" name="service_quantity[]">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control amount" placeholder="Total" id="amount" name="service_amount[]" readonly>
                            </div>  </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn removeService red btn-block" id="removeService" disabled="disabled"> Delete</button>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row pading-margin-zero">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-5" >
                                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control service_measer" placeholder="Enter Measurement of Service ..." name="service_measer[]"></textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-5" >
                                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control description service_description" placeholder="Description(s)" name="service_description[]" id="description"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>



                    <!--End Service Order Area-->
                </div>
            <!--Start Form Footer Area-->   
                <div class="form-action">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Total Amount</button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /btn-group -->
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="total_amount" style="font-size:25px; font-weight: bold">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">  
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Discount Amount</button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /btn-group -->
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount" name="discount_amount" style="font-size:25px;  font-weight: bold">
                          </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Advance Amount</button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /btn-group -->
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="advance_amount" name="advance_amount" style="font-size:25px;  font-weight: bold">
                          </div>
                         </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                               <button type="submit" class="btn purple btn-block">Submit Order</button>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            <!--End Form Footer Area-->
        </form>

    </div>
<script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            //Commom Script
            $('.dpicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true
            })
            var currentDate = new Date();
            $(".createdpicker").datepicker("setDate",currentDate);
            $("#loader").css("display",'none');
            $("#myDiv").removeAttr("style");
            $("#addService").removeAttr("disabled");

            //Start Order Form
            $('form').submit(function() {
                if ($.trim($("#service_cus_name").val()) === "") {
                    alert('Customer Name Field Empty');
                    return false;
                }else if( $.trim($("#service_cus_email").val()) === ""){
                    alert('Email Address Field Empty');
                    return false;
                }else if( $.trim($("#cell_number").val()) === ""){
                        alert('Cell Number Field Empty');
                        return false;
                }else if( $.trim($("#service_crete_date").val()) === ""){
                    alert('Create Date Field Empty');
                    return false;
                }else if( $.trim($("#service_delivery_date").val()) === ""){
                    alert('Delivery Date Field Empty');
                    return false;
                }else if( $.trim($("#service_cus_address").val()) === ""){
                    alert('Customer Address Field Empty');
                    return false;
                }
                var flag = 0;
                $(".service_qty").each(function(i){
                    if ($(this).val() == "")
                        flag++;
                });
                if(flag==0){
                    flagNew=0
                    $(".service_measer").each(function(i){
                        if ($(this).val() == "")
                            flagNew++;
                    });

                    if(flagNew==0){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        alert("All Measurement Fileds Requried");
                        return false;
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("All Service Quantity Fileds Requried");
                    return false;
                }




            });


            $("#addService").click(function(){
                //
                //alert('addButton');
                var serviceRowQty = $('.serviceRow').length;
                //alert(serviceRowQty);
                $("#orderBox:last").clone(true).insertAfter("div.serviceRow:last");
                $("div.serviceRow:last input").val('');
                $("div.serviceRow:last textarea").val('');
                $("div.serviceRow:last select").prop('selectedIndex',0);
                $("div.serviceRow:last label").text('');
                $("div.serviceRow .removeService").prop('disabled', false);
                return false;

            })

            $(document).on("click" , "#removeService" , function()  {
                //alert('deletebutton');
                var serviceRowQty = $('.serviceRow').length;
                if (serviceRowQty == 1){
                    $("div.serviceRow .removeService").prop('disabled', true);
                    return false;
                    $(".serviceRow").css("display", "block");
                }else{
                    $(this).closest('.serviceRow').remove();

                    if(serviceRowQty==1){
                        //return false;
                        $("div.serviceRow .removeService").prop('disabled', true);
                        return false
                    }else{

                        $("div.serviceRow .removeService").prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                    //$(".serviceRow").remove();

                    return false;
                }
                alert();
                return false;
            });




            $('.serviceRow').delegate('.service_id','change',function(){
                ;
                var subdiv = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
                var cat_id = $(this).closest('.serviceRow').find('.service_id option:selected').attr('value');
                subdiv.find('.service_price').val('');
                //alert(cat_id);
                //var a =
                //alert(totalamount());

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }

                });

                $.ajax({

                    type     : 'get',
                    url      : 'get-orders-list-jason/'+cat_id+'',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    //date   : { cat_id: cat_id},
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        subdiv.find('.service_price').val(data.service_price);
                        var price = subdiv.find('.service_price').val();
                        var qty = subdiv.find('.service_qty').val();
                        var total = data.service_price * qty ;
                        subdiv.find('.amount').val(total);
                        $('#total').val(totalamount());
                        //alert(alert(JSON.stringify(subdiv)));
                    },

                    error: function(error) {
                        //alert("Data retrive faield");
                    }

                });


                $(".serviceRow").delegate('.service_qty', "keyup",function(){
                    //alert('keyup');
                    var subdiv = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
                    var price = subdiv.find('.service_price').val();
                    var qty = subdiv.find('.service_qty').val();
                    var discount = $('#discount').val();
                    var total = price * qty ;
                    subdiv.find('.amount').val(total);
                    $('#total').val(totalamount());
                    //alert('background-color');
                    //$("p").css("background-color", "pink");
                });

                $("#discount").keyup(function(){
                    $('#total').val(totalamount());
                });




                function totalamount(t){
                    var t=0;
                    $('.amount').each(function(i,e){
                        var amt = $(this).val()-0;
                        t+=amt;

                    });
                    var d = $('#discount').val();
                    total = t-d;
                    return total;

                    $('.total').html(t);
                }

            });

            $('.serviceRow').each(function() {
                $(this).find('select').change(function(){//alert($(this).val())
                    if( $('.serviceRow').find('select option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1){
                        $(this).val($(this).css("border","1px red solid"));
                        alert('option is already selected');
                        $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
                    }else{
                        $(this).css("border","1px #D2D6DE solid");
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

**Order Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Service;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\lib\Custom;
use App\lib\DBQuery;
use App\Order;
use DB;
use App\Orderdetail;
use App\Session;
use App\ShopInfo;
use App\Payment;
use Auth;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function getOrders(){

        $orders = Order::All();
        //return $orders; 
        return view('order.allorderlist',compact('orders'));
    }

    public function getOrderajax($cat_id)
    {  
        $orders = Service::where('id',$cat_id)->first();
        return $orders;
    }

    public function addOrder()
    {
            $services = Service::where('active_status',0)->get();
            return view('order.addneworder',compact('services'));    
    }

     public function saveOrder(Request $request)
    { 

        if($request->discount_amount==""){
            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Order::$rules);
            $request['discount_amount']=0;
        }else{
            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Order::$numberrules);
        }


        if($validator->fails()){
            $services = Service::where('active_status',0)->get();
            return view('order.addneworder',compact('services'))->withErrors($validator);
        }else{

            $order = DBQuery::saveOrder($request);
            //return   $order;
            $shopinfo = ShopInfo::find(1);
            $total_bill_word = Custom::convert_number_to_words($number = $order->total_amount);
            return view('report.invsaveprint',compact('order','shopinfo','total_bill_word'));

        }
    }

    public function addOrderExCustomer($order_id)
    {       $order = Order::where('id',$order_id)->first();
            $services = Service::where('active_status',0)->get();
            return view('order.addneworderexcus',compact('services','order'));    
    }

     public function saveOrderExCustomer(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Order::$rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            $services = Service::where('active_status',0)->get();
            $order = Order::where('id',$request->order_id)->first();
            return view('order.addneworderexcus',compact('services','order'))->withErrors($validator);
        }else{

            $order = DBQuery::saveOrder($request);
            $shopinfo = ShopInfo::find(1);
            $total_bill_word = Custom::convert_number_to_words($number = $order->total_amount);
            return view('report.invupdateprint',compact('order','shopinfo','total_bill_word'));

        }
    }

    public function updateOrderById($order_id){ 
        $order = Order::where('id',$order_id)->first();
        $services = Service::All();
        return view('order.editOrder',compact('services','order'));
    }

    public function saveUpdateOrderById(Request $request){

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Order::$rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            $services = Service::where('active_status',0)->get();
            $order = Order::where('id', '=', $request->order_id)->first();
            //return $order;
            return view('order.editOrder',compact('services','order'))->withErrors($validator);
        }else{
            DBQuery::saveUpdateOrder($request);
            $order = Order::where('id', '=', $request->order_id)->first();
           //return $order ;
            $shopinfo = ShopInfo::find(1);
            $total_bill_word = Custom::convert_number_to_words($number = $order->total_amount);
            return view('report.newinvoice',compact('order','shopinfo','total_bill_word'));
        }

    }

    public function deliveryOrderById($order_id){
        $order = Order::where('id',$order_id)->first();
        //return   $order;
        $services = Service::All();
        return view('order.deliveryorder',compact('services','order'));
    }

    public function saveDeliveryOrderById($order_id){

        //$a = Auth::user()->is_permission;
        //return $order_id;
        //if(Auth::user()->is_permission==1){
             Order::where('id',$order_id)
                ->update(array('service_status' => 3));
       // }
        $order = Order::where('id',$order_id)->first();
        return view('order.deliveryorder',compact('order'));
    }

}

**The order codes**

<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{

    protected $table = "orders";

    protected $fillable = [ 
                            'service_ref',
                            'service_status',
                            'order_create_by',
                            'service_crete_date',
                            'service_delivery_date',
                            'service_cus_name',
                            'cell_number',
                            'service_cus_email',
                            'service_cus_address',                          
                            'total_amount',
                            'discount_amount',
                        ];

    public static $numberrules = array(
                    'service_cus_name'        =>'required',
                    'service_cus_address'     =>'required',
                    'service_cus_email'       =>'required',
                    'service_crete_date'      =>'required',
                    'service_delivery_date'   =>'required',
                    'total_amount'            =>'required',
                    'discount_amount'         =>'numeric|',
                    'cell_number'             =>'required|numeric',
                    'service_quantity.*'      =>'required|numeric',
                    'service_id.*'            =>'required',
                    'service_measer.*'        =>'required',
                    'service_description.*'   =>'required',

        );

    public static $rules = array(
        'service_cus_name'        =>'required',
        'service_cus_address'     =>'required',
        'service_cus_email'       =>'required',
        'cell_number'             =>'required|numeric',
        'service_crete_date'      =>'required',
        'service_delivery_date'   =>'required',
        'total_amount'            =>'required',
        'service_quantity.*'      =>'required|numeric',
        'service_id.*'            =>'required',
        'service_measer.*'        =>'required',
        'service_description.*'   =>'required',

    );

    public function orderdetails() {

        //return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail','fid','id');
        return $this->hasMany('App\Orderdetail','order_id','id');
    }

    public function user() {

        //return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail','fid','id');
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','ser_act_create_by');
    }
    public function payments() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Payment','order_id','id');
        //return $this->>belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

**Order Details Code**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Orderdetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = "orderdetails";

        protected $fillable = [ 
                            'order_id',
                            'service_id',
                            'service_price',
                            'service_quantity',
                            'service_amount',
                            'service_measer',
                            'service_description',
                            'service_id',


                        ];

    public function order() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
        //return $this->>belongsTo('App\Order');
    }


    public function service() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Service','service_id','id');
        //return $this->>belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add the field to the database, did you add it manually/through a `migration`?

Comment: I added it manually...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @WouterVanDamme, I wasn't getting any error. It added all values to the datbase except for that one.

Comment: Why is the field called `service_description[]` instead of `service_description`? Is there more than one textarea with this name?

Comment: and does `service_measer` gets stored in the database? could u check?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, because it is an array.

Comment: @Sletheren, yes it does.

Comment: try to use `php artisan tinker` then `$test = \App\Order::create([data..])` and try to create an order manually after see the fields u get, its hard to tel whats wrong, but it seems logical what u have now, also u can try to make it only a simple variable `service_description` not an array and test if it gonna work..

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the table structure?

Comment: Is `service_description` in the the `$request`? Otherwise; what does `DBQuery::saveOrder()` ?